# Controls.Add(tabPage) vs. TabPages.Add(tabPage)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

To create a new tab in winform application I found this in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984280(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
TabPage tabPage1 = new TabPage(title);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1);
```

But when I add a tab manually from Form1.cs[Design] Visual Studio automatically creates this in Form1.Designer.cs for a new tab:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
```

So, what is the main difference between `tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage1)` and     `tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1);` ?

Comment: Basically no difference - [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,7bc75a420d7bf90b,references). I guess the former is more convenient since it emulates a typed `TabPage` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. Here is the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,7bc75a420d7bf90b) for `TabPageCollection.Add` method:

```
public void Add(TabPage value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    owner.Controls.Add(value);
}
```

In above code, the `owner` is the `TabControl` which owns the `TabPageCollection`.

The benefit of using [`TabPageCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) is in 5 different overloads which it provides for adding tab pages to the `TabControl.`

Comment: Although source code (implementation) should not be used for describing the contract / behavior of a class :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I used it as an evidence ;)

Comment: Just kidding - I was typing the same as comment. Nice to see you, haven't been in touch for a while (I moved to other areas). Hope you are doing great!

Comment: @IvanStoev Just out of curiosity, what is the reason for that?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Reason for what? The comment?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Well, normally the class interface and behavior should be defined and documented, so you don't need to look at the implementation in order to determine the reason for a class method, how it should work and when you should use it.

Comment: @emiraslan The designer generates such code, because the tab page actually adds to `Controls` collection of the `TabControl` and in the in `TabControlDesigner` after adding a tab page in `InitializeNewComponent` or `OnAdd`, always the the designer notifies about `Controls` property changing by calling `RaiseComponentChanging`.